# Python dict into highcharts bar chart dataset

Tags: python, dictionary, highcharts

I'm building a dict with data that I extract from SQLAlchemy, the dict builds fine, but my problem is putting that data into a bar chart using highcharts.

What I have is:

**__init__.py**

```
@app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard(chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'bar', chart_height = 350):
    i = 1
    counts = {}
    counts = build_row_count()
    chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height,}
    series = [{"name": counts.keys(), "data": counts.values()}]
    title = {"text": 'Assets'}
    xAxis = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
    yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'yAxis Label'}}
    return render_template("dashboard.html", TOPIC_DICT = TOPIC_DICT, row_count=counts, locations=get_locations(), i=i, chartID=chartID, chart=chart, series=series, title=title, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis)
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<div id={{ chartID|safe }} class="chart" style="height: 100px; width: 500px"></div>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="chart_ID" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script>
    var chart_id = {{ chartID|safe }}
    var series = {{ series|safe }}
    var title = {{ title|safe }}
    var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }}
    var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
    var chart = {{ chart|safe }}
</script>
```

On the one hand I can see the container, but nothing in it. So everything on the page just moved down.

**Page Source:**

```
<div id=chart_ID class="chart" style="height: 100px; width: 500px"></div>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="chart_ID" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script>
    var chart_id = chart_ID
    var series = [{'data': [1, 53, 323, 1, 1, 39], 'name': ['MENLYN', 'OR_TAMBO', 'KRUGER_AVE', 'CENTURIONMALL_E1', 'NEDBANK_ATM', 'PRETORIA']}]
    var title = {'text': 'Assets'}
    var xAxis = {'categories': ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
    var yAxis = {'title': {'text': 'yAxis Label'}}
    var chart = {'renderTo': 'chart_ID', 'type': 'bar', 'height': 350}
</script>
```

**Problem:** How can I make that dict conform to the charts dataset/series format requirement? And is that the reason why the chart is not showing?

So I can see the data in the dict is being pulled through. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your JS fails because of this line: `var chart_id = chart_ID` - don't you have any errors in JS console? Also, don't forget to create chart from your options: `new Highcharts.chart({ chart: chart, yAxis: yAxis, xAxis: xAxis, title: title, series: series });`. And create chart **after** page is loaded (onload event). Do you have jQuery or standalone adapter included? I don't see one of them in your page source.

Comment: I have jQuery and call highcharts JS remotely.

Comment: Still, how about my first question? It looks like assigning variable `chart_ID`to variable `chart_id` (while `chart_ID` is not defined), but since you didn't post fully generated page source (or setup live demo?) I can only guess. Once again, I suggest to start with checking JavaScript console - there most probably are errors with details why it fails.